# How do you use global in this scenerio?

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to coding and I don't really understand how to use a lot of these codes. It would help me a lot if someone told me how to do use `global` in this scenario..

```py
def tshirtadd():
    global perch
    perch = 0
    print("you have",perch,"T-shirts")
    add = int(input("how many t-shirts would you like to add? "))
    perch+add
    return perch


def tshirtremove():
    global perch
    print("You have",perch,"Tshirts")
    remove = int(input("How many Tshirts would you like to remove? "))

    perch - remove

    return perch


def order():
    global perch
    print(perch)
    print(perch*10)
    return main


def main():
    ordering = int(input("Would you like to add,remove, view order, or purchase?"))
    print(list1)
    count = 0
    for x in list1:
        count = count+1
        print(count,"\b)",x)
    perch = 0

    if ordering == 1:
        tshirtadd()
        print("you have",perch,"Tshirts")
        return main()
    elif ordering == 2:
        tshirtremove()
        return main()
    elif ordering == 3:
        order()
        return main()
    else:
        exit
    print(perch)
main()
```

Comment: Do you have a requirement to use `global`? Typically it is not pythonic to use `global`.

Comment: there are few other mistakes in your code.

 I don't think you need to set the perch to 0 in the `tshirtadd()` function. 

in `tshirtremove()` function `perch - remove` need to be `perch = perch - remove`

in the main function, you are using the `list1` without defining it

Comment: "how to use global in this scenario?" is *don't* an acceptable answer? There is nothing about your code fragment that makes it seem like it is a valid use-case for global variables.

Answer (score 0):

you should initialize the variable perch before using global, `perch = 0` should be on the top before the function definitions.

i think you are trying to initialize perch in the main function, but that is not how global work, you need to define it outside before all the functions and you can use the global perch inside the `main()` just like other functions and set it to zero there if you want

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: 
We usually use `global` when we want our variable to be accessed from anywhere. SO you just need to define `global variable` just once and you can use it anywhere.

I have made a few changes to your code. (Few more changes are required but not sure what this code really wants to achieve)

This might help you understant concept of `global`

```
def tshirtadd():

        print("you have",perch,"T-shirts")
        add = int(input("how many t-shirts would you like to add? "))
        perch += add
        return perch


    def tshirtremove():
        print("You have",perch,"Tshirts")
        remove = int(input("How many Tshirts would you like to remove? "))

        perch -= remove

        return perch


    def order():
        print(perch)
        print(perch*10)
        return main


    def main():
        global perch
        perch = 0
        ordering = int(input("Would you like to add,remove, view order, or purchase?"))
        print(list1)
        count = 0
        for x in list1:
            count = count+1
            print(count,"\b)",x)
        perch = 0

        if ordering == 1:
            tshirtadd()
            print("you have",perch,"Tshirts")
            return main()
        elif ordering == 2:
            tshirtremove()
            return main()
        elif ordering == 3:
            order()
            return main()
        else:
            exit
        print(perch)
    main()
```